# How do you specify an exception in an iCal feed?

Tags: c#, icalendar

I am working on creating an iCal feed for our application. Things are going well. I have everything working except *exceptions*. For example when you schedule a recurring event and need to cancel a day, I am using the **EXDATE** tag in the feed and that is working fine for removing a scheduled occurrence.

The issues is if you have a recurring event that starts today @ 2pm and recurrs 5 times. In our application the user can change any one of those weeks to start @ 3pm if needed. How to I specify that in the iCal feed?

I have been looking at the documentation, but must be missing something...

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

Drowsy is on the right track.

1. The UID's MUST match so that the adjusment is recognised as
   belonging to the original event.
2. The Recurrence Id matches it to the instance of the recurring sequence that is being modified. 
   This is because of    course one might be changing the date and time
   as well as other    changes and one doesn't want the original
   instance there generated by    the recurring spec, as well as the
   modification.
3. And yes finally the sequence id must be there so
   that one knows the sequence or layer of    modifications in case
   there are several.

For example - here's a dump of what google calendar generates if you modify a recurring event.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140325T084000
DTEND;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140325T101000
DTSTAMP:20140327T060506Z
UID:vu2d4gjdj4mpfuvas53qi32s7k@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140325T083000
CREATED:20131216T033331Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140327T060215Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test Event
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT


BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140128T083000
DTEND;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20140128T100000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20141208T213000Z;BYDAY=TU
DTSTAMP:20140327T060506Z
UID:vu2d4gjdj4mpfuvas53qi32s7k@google.com
CREATED:20131216T033331Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140222T101012Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test event
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: Can the same approach be used to mark an instance as removed? If so, how would one mark an event as removed/deleted?

Comment: According to the RFC 5545 spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.11  one should issue an update with a status of cancelled.     Interstingly if you 'cancel'/delete an event in google calendar it just drops it right out of the ics file (no updated status).  If one deletes a singleinstance out of a recurring sequence, it issues that as an EXDATE.     Note as always updates only work if people have subscribed to the ics feed, NOT if they import or 'add to google'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe as long as you generate a record with a RECURRENCE-ID based on the original time, and using the original UID you should be able to set the DTSTART and DTEND values for a single instance.   You would need to increment the SEQUENCE too.  That should trigger updates on client software.